# Trying to connect module pom and parent pom. How do I set the relative path?

Tags: maven, relative-path, pom.xml, multi-module, tycho

I haven't found an appropriate example for this, so I ask here:

My project structure is

```
workspace
|
|-->plugins
| |
| --> some.plugin.folder
| |
| --> parentpom.xml
| 
|-->tests
  |
  |-->some.test.plugin.folder
    |
    |--> pom.xml
```

Okay, I can add test modules in the parentpom.xml.

```
<module>../tests/some.test.plugin.folder</module>
```

But I can't for the life of me find the correct relative path to the parent pom in the pom.xml of the test plugin.

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>../../plugins/parentpom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Can someone help me? Or is it impossible to use two ../ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path in your module called ***some.test.plugin.folder*** should be a path only and not contain a file name. It should be:

```
<relativePath>../../plugins</relativePath>
```

Also your parent module should have a `pom.xml`, so rename `parentpom.xml` to `pom.xml`.